# Retire Custom entity

Tags: guidewire, claimcenter

There is a newly customized new entity, but business doesn't want to use it in future and code has been merged into higher environments. I want to retire this customized entity. May I know how can we achieve this? I know about deprecated but we can use this for column present in the entities. This won't help because I want to retire whole entity. Please suggest.

Comment: I don't think so its doable , try ask Guidewire Team..  we can do delete the entity completely  instead retire

Answer (score 6):

If this has not made it to production, the recommendation is to remove the entity and drop the lower environment databases.

If in production or dropping is not an option:

> You can implement the IDatamodelUpgrade plugin and write
> IDatamodelChange upgrade triggers to synchronize the database with the
> data model. Guidewire supports the functions dropTable and dropColumn
> to assist in this process.

Since this sounds like a first time data-model update, I do recommend opening a case with Guidewire Support to review your update.

Quoted documentation is in the Guidewire docs:
https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/pc/202302/config/config/topics/c_eb2317371.html

Please pay attention to the warning in the docs as well:

> **WARNING**: Be very careful of making changes to the data model on a live
> production database. Some changes might invalidate your installation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `remove()` function to retire the entity.  This method is designed for simple custom entities which are normally not associated with other entities. So please do check if your custom entity is associated other entities before using `remove()` function. Thanks.

Comment: remove() -> will do retire the column not entity

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use it and there are no rows against this table, you could use the IDataModelUpgrade trigger and write a custom trigger to drop the table and column.